#  How to specify page width and length for printed (or html) report?

Tags: ms-access, report

The default report (when I export to html) seems to be for standard 8.5" x 11" paper. 
What settings do I need to change so that the width and height are 6" x 9" for example.
Thanks.

Comment: Hm, when I export to html there is no such restriction. How do you export it and what version of access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Access 2003 or below, with the report open in Design View, go to the File menu and choose Page Setup. The Page tab has the settings for page size, etc.